# I cant sort a multidimensional array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I´m working in a controller, when I get the $result, I try to order it by date, this is my function to order:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $a = strtotime($a[2]);
    $b = strtotime($b[2]);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
 }
```

And I call the function cmp inside a function:

```
usort($result, "cmp");
```

I tried even calling simple functions like "function prueba(){return "hola";} but I can´t do it, Why?

Everything is right, if I comment the call to the function 'cmp' everything works fine, but I can´t order the $result.

Someone can help me?

EDIT:

Now I´m working with SortBy, but I cannot order the collection:

```
    $sorted = $result->sortByDesc('timestamp');
    $sorted->values()->all();

    $data = $sorted[0]['ftimestamp'];
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Is $result actually an array? Or is it a Collection object?

Comment: Mmmm, could be a collection object. If I call getType($result) I get "object"

Comment: If it's a Collection, then you have a [sortBy()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby) method that will accept a callback.... or add an ORDER BY Clause to your database statement

Comment: I´m working with DynamoDB, I don´t know if I cant set an Order By. Then, I cant sort $result with sortBy()?

Comment: Well if it is a Collection object, then you should be able to use the sortBy() method, even if you cant order it in the database retrieval

Comment: With sortBy I get an error 500, I´m reading this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby Maybe could be just for collections with one dimension?

Comment: Well the chances are that you have a collection of objects, not of arrays; but if you get an error 500 then look in the laravel log to see what the error is

Comment: So you'll need to see what the object properties are.... what model were you returning? and what properties does it have?

Comment: The last one, now I don´t get Error 500, but it dont order my $result. Other idea? Thanks

Comment: sortBy returns a new collection, it doesn't sort the existing collection (not like usort being "by reference" for array sorting)

Comment: $sorted = $result->sortBy('timestamp');
        $sorted->values()->all();
        
        $data = $sorted[0]['timestamp'];

I think I´m very close to the answer, but sorted is not sorted =(, I ´m just following the documentation.